# Inject ILogger when adding a Singleton for Azure Functions 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

I have a redisprovider class in my Azure Function:

```
        public RedisCacheProvider(ILogger<RedisCacheProvider> logger,
            IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            multiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
        }
```

I am adding this class as a singleton but how do I initialise the Ilogger in the startup class. I am aware it is injected by Azure Functions into the classes. If so, how do I manage this in the startup class when we need to initialise other objects for the class on startup?

```
 services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(serviceProvider =>
                    new RedisCacheProvider(**???**, serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>()));
```

Usually, I do this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpService, HttpService>();
```

In the RedisProvider class, I need to pass my connection string. So how do I inject the ILogger when I pass the IConnectionMultiplexer?

Comment: To supply _some_ of the parameters but leave the rest up to the container, we can use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(serviceProvider, customParam1, customParam2, ...)`. If we expect to do it often, we can compile an efficient, reusable factory using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(type, customParam1, customParam2, ...)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to manage construction manually, since you need to inject settings. This raises the question of how to inject the subdependencies, which is normally managed by the container.

Actually, we can acquire the subdependencies just like you already do for the multiplexer!

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(serviceProvider => new RedisCacheProvider(
    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>(),
    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>()));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I think I had done something wrong initially when doing the same for the ILogger.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid creating singletons like that. Instead of passing the connection string, consider passing `IOptions<RedisOption>` to your `RedisCacheProvider` in order to access the connection string within the constructor. This would also allow you to register your service like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider, RedisCacheProvider>()
```

Further reading: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)